# Weird double question marks in the query string parameters with fetch api and laravel

Tags: php, laravel, fetch-api, aurelia

Facing a very weird problem when posting query string params from browser(chrome) using fetch API and then parsing the params on server side with php-laravel, the parameter key is getting prepended with double question marks.

I am using aurelia fetch client if that matters.

```
let url = new URL('https://myapp.com/api/companies/');
    let param = {'id_owner': 34};
    url.search = new URLSearchParams(param);
    this.http.fetch(url, {
      mode: 'cors',
      method: 'get'
    })
```

on server side when I try to access `id_owner` nothing shows up.
I added the following line in my controller(laravel) and the output

```php
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        return [$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $_POST, $_GET, $request->query('??id_owner'), $request->all()];
```

and surprisingly the output contains double question marks prepended to the key

```
[
"\/api\/companies\/?id_owner=34", // [$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
"??id_owner=34",      // $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']
[],                   // $_POST
{"??id_owner":"34"},  // $_GET
"34",                 // $request->query('??id_owner') , a laravel feature
{"??id_owner":"34"}   // $request->all() , again a laravel feature
]
```

Ideally it should be simple and straightforward to use $_GET['id_owner'] to get the value but with added question marks it doesn't work. Where are they coming from ? Any idea what is going wrong?

Comment: sounds like a url encoding problem before sending it to PHP. Can you try a console log before sending the request?

Comment: what is the output from `https://myapp.com/api/companies/` ? before you start process.

Comment: console log before posting the request 
```href: "https://myapp.com/api/companies/?id_owner=34"```

Comment: @Bira when I access the url `https://myapp.com/api/companies/` I get this JSON
```["\/api\/companies","?",[],{"?":""},null,{"?":null}]```

Comment: I don't know if it can help but check this : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14531. This issue is about that the 1st parameter only has a preceding `?`. An in the comment a PULL REQUEST was refused because they said : Obsolete since `URLSearchParams` (Angular's) has been deprecated, while `HttpParams` does NOT support parsing string yet.